# Windows metro app UI messes in high resolution devices when SwapChainBackgroundPanel is replaced by SwapChainPanel

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, direct3d11

I am developing winRt metro application. I was using SwapChainBackgroundPanel in UI for showing video content.
 I recently replaced it by SwapChainPanel because Microsoft recommends it.
But now the UI is stretched beyond the screen.
If I don't convert dips to pixels while resizing swapchain buffers , The UI looks fine.
I am seeing this problem in Surface pro 3 and other high resolution devices

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with `SwapChainPanel`, you have to take the properties `CompositionScaleX` and `CompositionScaleY` into consideration.
Just before `m_swapChain->GetBuffer()`, insert the following code:

```
// Setup inverse scale on the swap chain
DXGI_MATRIX_3X2_F inverseScale = { 0 };
inverseScale._11 = 1.0f / m_swapChainPanel->CompositionScaleX;
inverseScale._22 = 1.0f / m_swapChainPanel->CompositionScaleY;
ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain2> spSwapChain2;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    m_swapChain.As<IDXGISwapChain2>(&spSwapChain2)
);

DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    spSwapChain2->SetMatrixTransform(&inverseScale)
);
```